# Creating Breeze.js query with DateTimeOffset fails

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

I am running Breeze.WebApi v1.2.5 and I am also having problems with querying DateTimeOffset types.

Here is my query:

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Sessions')
                       .where('startTime', ">", new Date(2013, 3, 19));
```

This generates

```
http://localhost/api/breeze/Sessions?$filter=StartTime%20gt%20datetime'2013-04-19T05%3A00%3A00.000Z'
```

*Which throws an error.*

However, if I manually change the above generated query to use datetimeoffset (instead of datetime)   Like so:

```
http://localhost/api/breeze/Sessions?$filter=StartTime%20gt%20datetimeoffset'2013-04-19T05%3A00%3A00.000Z'
```

It queries correctly and returns the appropriate response.

How can I get breeze to generate the appropriate query with datetimeoffset, instead of datetime?

Comment: You should probably use new `new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2013, 3, 19), TimeSpan.Zero)`

Comment: Are you using the WebApi adapter or the OData adapter?

Comment: I'm using WebApi (asp.net mvc 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of **v 1.2.7**, this has been fixed

--- previous post

Ok, I've repro'd this.  We should have a fix in the next release. I will post back here when it is released. and thx for finding it.

Comment: Awesome.  Any idea of an ETA?  or a quick word around?

Comment: Should be before Monday - ... or you can fish out the updated breeze.debug.js from github.  I just checked in the fix, but am still testing.

Comment: You are rocking my socks. Thanks for the help.